# Why the fuzzy pinyin can't take effect in fcitx5-rime input method engine?

Tags: ime, fuzzy, fcitx, pinyin

Rime is an input method engine for entering Chinese characters, supporting a wide range of input methods.`fcitx5-rime` is the rime running on fcitx5 input method framework.
I have installed fcitx5-rime in my os which contains the below info:

```
uname -a
Linux debian 5.10.0-22-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 5.10.178-3 (2023-04-22) x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

`fcitx5-rime`'s version:

```
dpkg -l  fcitx5-rime
Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
|/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)
||/ Name              Version      Architecture Description
+++-=================-============-============-====================================
ii  fcitx5-rime:amd64 5.0.4-1      amd64        Rime input method support for fcitx5
```

I write the configuration in `luna_pinyin.custom.yaml`:

```
cat luna_pinyin.custom.yaml
patch:
  'speller/algebra':
    - erase/^xx$/                      

    - derive/^([zcs])h/$1/             # zh, ch, sh => z, c, s
    - derive/^([zcs])([^h])/$1h$2/     # z, c, s => zh, ch, sh

    - derive/([ei])n$/$1ng/            # en => eng, in => ing
    - derive/([ei])ng$/$1n/            # eng => en, ing => in

    - abbrev/^([a-z]).+$/$1/          
    - abbrev/^([zcs]h).+$/$1/
```

Wherever to put the file ,`$HOME/.config/fcitx5/rime/` or `$HOME/.local/share/fcitx5/rime/`,the fuzzy pinyin setting (speller)still can't take effect in fcitx5-rime input method engine?
1.Is the configuration wrong?
2.Which directory can i put it in?
How to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in [`fcitx/fcitx5` discussion 372](https://github.com/fcitx/fcitx5/discussions/372), consider running the [`fcitx5-diagnose.sh`](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/fcitx/fcitx5/master/data/fcitx5-diagnose.sh), in case it detects other factors which would explain your issue.

You can review its output, for the following sections:

- **Fcitx State Check**: Make sure `fcitx5` and `fcitx5-rime` are running correctly.
- **Configuration UI Check**: Verify that the configuration interfaces for `fcitx5` are accessible and functioning.
- **Frontends Setup Check**: Look for any issues with the input method framework setup, especially regarding environment variables and input method modules.
- **Module and Addons Check**: Confirm that all necessary modules and addons, especially those related to `fcitx5-rime`, are enabled and working properly.
- **Input Methods Check**: Although this might not directly review `luna_pinyin.custom.yaml`, it can still provide insights into the overall input method configuration.

The default location of `luna_pinyin.custom.yaml` seems to be `$HOME/.config/fcitx5/rime/`.

Answer (score 0):

1. In Fcitx 5, the directory is `~/.local/share/fcitx5/rime/`, unless you set XDG_DATA_HOME to something else (it's actually $XDG_DATA_HOME/fcitx5/rime). You got that right.
2. You need to make sure you're luna_pinyin. Most likely you do, but you can check with Ctrl + ` to make sure.
3. luna_pinyin.custom.yaml file name is correct. Here's the content in my data directory, FYI:

```
$ ls ~/.local/share/fcitx5/rime
build  installation.yaml  luna_pinyin.custom.yaml  luna_pinyin.userdb  sync  user.yaml
```

4. You need re-deploy to make it take effect. Restart fcitx5 should also trigger a deploy check.

I can guarantee that your luna_pinyin.custom.yaml works for me.

[image: with luna_pinyin.custom.yaml]

[image: without luna_pinyin.custom.yaml]

So you are most likely missing the last step.

If you still can't get it work, I can suggest you try to use `strace -f fcitx5 -r 2>&1 | grep luna_pinyin.custom.yaml` to see the actual path it tries to load. There might be some other reason that I can't predict. strace trace system call so it can be use to inspect what files does the process try to accces. You may also change the grep string to do your own investigation.

On my system, the output looks like (I don't have luna_pinyin.custom.yaml when I produce this output so it's ENOENT):

```
[pid 459614] statx(AT_FDCWD, "/home/XXXXX/.local/share/fcitx5/rime/luna_pinyin.custom.yaml", AT_STATX_SYNC_AS_STAT|AT_NO_AUTOMOUNT, STATX_TYPE|STATX_MODE, 0x7fd3df8e9e90) = -1 ENOENT
[pid 459614] statx(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/share/rime-data/luna_pinyin.custom.yaml", AT_STATX_SYNC_AS_STAT|AT_NO_AUTOMOUNT, STATX_TYPE|STATX_MODE, 0x7fd3df8e9e90) = -1 ENOENT
```

Answer (score 0):

I upgrade my os into debian12.04,installed rime and fcitx5,the fuzzy pinyin can be called.